# Generic Deserializing : JSON ID value to Object

Tags: php, json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

### What I'm using:

I'm using the [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) to deserialize my `JSON object` from a POST request.

### Description of the problem:

One of the vaules in my `JSON` is an `Id`. I'd like to replace this Id with the correct object before the deserialization occurs.

Unfortunately, `JMSSerializerBundle` does not have a `@preDeserializer` annotation.

The problem I'm facing (and that I would have faced if there was an @preDeserializer annotation anyway) is that I would like to create a generic function for all my entities.

### Question:

How do I replace my `Id` with the corresponding `object` in the most generic way possible ?

Comment: it does have a pre_deserialize  event http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system#serializer-pre-deserialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also do your own hydratation as I did (with Doctrine):

### **Solution**

The `IHydratingEntity` is an interface which all my entities implement.
The `hydrate` function is used in my BaseService generically. Parameters are the entity and the json object.

At each iteration, the function will test if the method exists then it will call the `reflection` function to check if the parameter's method (setter) also implements `IHydratingEntity`.
If it's the case, I use the `id` to get the entity from the database with Doctrine ORM.

I think it's possible to optimize this process, so please be sure to share your thoughts !

```
protected function hydrate(IHydratingEntity $entity, array $infos)
{
    #->Verification
    if (!$entity) exit;
    #->Processing
    foreach ($infos as $clef => $donnee)
    {
        $methode = 'set'.ucfirst($clef);
        if (method_exists($entity, $methode))
        {
            $donnee = $this->reflection($entity, $methode, $donnee);
            $entity->$methode($donnee);
        }
    }
}

public function reflection(IHydratingEntity $entity, $method, $donnee)
{
    #->Variable declaration
    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($entity);
    #->Verification
    $idData = intval($donnee);
    #->Processing
    foreach($reflectionClass->getMethod($method)->getParameters() as $param)
    {
        if ($param->getClass() != null)
        {
            if ($param->getClass()->implementsInterface(IEntity::class))
                #->Return
                return $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($param->getClass()->name)->find($idData);
        }
    }
    #->Return
    return $donnee;
}
```